# Browser: Open Default Home Page

Tags: android, android-browser

Does anybody know how to open the default home page in Android?
If I use this code, the browser will open www.google.com

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(i);
```

but, how can I instruct the browser to open the home page?

Do I need to get the home page from the Browser settings (how??) first or it just a matter of adding a flag to the intent?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133650/android-intent-to-open-users-preferred-browser), this is what you need to do:

```
String packageName = "com.android.browser"; 
String className = "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity"; 
Intent internetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
internetIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER); 
internetIntent.setClassName(packageName, className); 
mHomeActivity.startActivity(internetIntent);
```