# Browser Intent: Opting to "Use by default for this action" stops working in next requests

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an Android application and it has an activity in which I use the following code to open a url in browser

```
// show url view intent         
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(currentAdUrl));
startActivity(intent);
```

Everything works fine if I don't opt to

> Use by default for this action [image: Use by default for this action.]

However, once I opt to use default, the browser stops opening.

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it using following

```
// show url view intent         
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(currentAdUrl));
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open with");
startActivity(chooser);
```

Got the answer from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12685895/1237297).